# Spring annotated controller works, but router/handler approach does not appear to retrieve *Mono<>* from *ServerRequest*

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Still playing around and trying to understand the "how" of Spring's Webflux and Reactor.

The following successfully adds a new *DemoPOJO* to the repo when the annotated controller is used (i.e., *POST* issued at *//localhost:8080/v1/DemoPOJO*).

However, when issuing the same *POST* using the router/handler implementation (i.e., *//localhost:8080/v2/DemoPOJO*), *request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class)* does not appear to retrieve the *DemoPOJO* instance from the *ServerRequest* (i.e., *DemoPOJO.printme()* is not being invoked).

I'm "working on this", but thought I'd see if anyone can help me "get there faster". For-what-it's-worth, the router/handler implementations (i.e., *GET*) that don't require getting a *DemoPOJO* out of *ServerRequest* are working.

RESTful endpoints using annotation...

```
@RestController
public class DemoPOJOController {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    DemoPOJOService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/v1/DemoPOJO")
    public Mono<Boolean> addDemoPOJO(@RequestBody DemoPOJO demoPOJO) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJOController.addDemoPOJO( {} )", demoPOJO.getId());
        return service.add(demoPOJO);
    }
}
```

"Router" part of the corresponding router/handler implementation...

```
@Configuration
public class DemoPOJORouter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(DemoPOJOHandler requestHandler) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJORouter.route( DemoPOJOHandler )");
        return nest(path("/v2"),
                nest(accept(APPLICATION_JSON),
                        RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.POST("/DemoPOJO"), requestHandler::add)));
    }
}
```

"Handler" part of the router/handler implementation...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOHandler {

    public static final String PATH_VAR_ID = "id";

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private DemoPOJOService service;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

        request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(DemoPOJO::printMe);
        return ServerResponse.ok().build();
    }
}
```

*DemoPOJORepo* implementation (hoping to simplify my learning experience by avoiding a "real" repository)...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJORepo {

    private static final int NUM_OBJS = 15;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJORepo.class);

    private static DemoPOJORepo demoRepo = null;

    private Map<Integer, DemoPOJO> demoPOJOMap;

    private DemoPOJORepo() {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJORepo.DemoPOJORepo()");
        initMap();
    }

    public boolean add(DemoPOJO demoPOJO) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJORepo.add( DemoPOJO )");
        boolean pojoAdded = false;

        if (!demoPOJOMap.containsKey(demoPOJO.getId())) {
            logger.debug("DemoPOJORepo.add( DemoPOJO ) -> adding for id {}", demoPOJO.getId());
            demoPOJOMap.put(demoPOJO.getId(), demoPOJO);
            pojoAdded = true;
        }
        return pojoAdded;
    }

    private void initMap() {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJORepo.initMap()");
        demoPOJOMap = new TreeMap<Integer, DemoPOJO>();

        for (int ndx = 1; ndx < (NUM_OBJS + 1); ndx++) {
            demoPOJOMap.put(ndx, new DemoPOJO(ndx, "foo_" + ndx, ndx + 100));
        }
    }
}
```

The objects being manipulated...

```
public class DemoPOJO {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    public static final String DEF_NAME = "DEFAULT NAME";
    public static final int DEF_VALUE = 99;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public DemoPOJO(int id) {
        this(id, DEF_NAME, DEF_VALUE);
    }

    public DemoPOJO(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("value") int value) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJO.DemoPOJO( {}, {}, {} )", id, name, value);
        this.id    = id;
        this.name  = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // getters and setters go here

    public void printMe() {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJO.printMe()");
        System.out.printf("id->%d, name->%s, value->%d%n", id, name, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am guesstimating here since i am writing from mobile. But i think this is your problem.

```
request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(DemoPOJO::printMe);
return ServerResponse.ok().build();
```

You are thinking imperative, that first row will be executed then the second which is not the case in webflux. You have to think events-callbacks.

```
return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class)
            .doOnSuccess(DemoPOJO::printMe)
            .thenReturn(ServerResponse.ok().build());
```

I think this is it but i could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely gives me something to work against!

Comment: Update...Your suggestion worked, although I ended up changing "*'`.thenReturn(...)`*" to simply "*`.then(...)`*".